# shell script how to use $variable

Tags: shell, makefile, sh

I am doing a Makefile but I can't return the value of $var to use it in conditional sentences:

```
#!/bin/sh

GO=$(shell) go
GOPATH=$(GO) env GOPATH

make:
    @$(GOPATH)
    @if [ ! -d "$(GOPATH)/bin" ]; then mkdir -p "$(GOPATH)/bin" ; fi
```

When I type `make`, `@$GOPATH` returns `/home/icvallejo/go` but after, I don't know how to use it (I can't do it) with 'if' condition, `make` returns this:

if [ ! -d " go env GOPATH/bin" ] ; then mkdir -p " go env GOPATH/bin" ; fi

Can you help me please?

Comment: What is `go` and with is `GOPATH`?

Comment: I want to execute $go env GOPATH to take the GOPATH (golang) and keep it in $GOPATH. In fact, it works with `gmake` but not with `make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

GO := go
GOPATH := $(shell $(GO) env GOPATH)

make:
    @echo $(GOPATH)
    @if [ ! -d "$(GOPATH)/bin" ]; then mkdir -p "$(GOPATH)/bin" ; fi
```